# loop and conditional when adding a new object?

Tags: javascript

I try to do this:

```
posts[fbposts[fbpost].id] = ({
    name: fbposts[fbpost].from.name,
    link: "http://www.facebook.com/" + fbposts[fbpost].from.id,
    img: "http://graph.facebook.com/" + fbposts[fbpost].from.id + "/picture",
    message: fbposts[fbpost].message,
    to: ({
        name: name,
        link: link,
    }),
    created: timeDifference(Date.parse((fbposts[fbpost].updated_time))),
    sortvar: (Date.parse(fbposts[fbpost].updated_time)),
    comments: ({
        /* looping through the comments*/
        if (fbposts[fbpost].comments.count) {
            for (var comment in fbposts[fbpost].comments.data) {
                name: fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].from.name;
                link: "http://www.facebook.com/" + fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].from.id;
                img: "http://www.facebook.com/" + fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].from.id; + "/picture";
                message: fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].message;
                created: timeDifference(Date.parse(fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].created_time));
            }
        }
    })
});
}
```

But obviously when I get to the comment, the script brakes, as I can't run loops within and conditionals within the declaration of the object. How should I go about doing this instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you could do this using a closure...

```
comments: function() { ... looping code ...; return data}(),
```

What this will do is define an inline (single use) function and call it immediately, returning valid javascript as a result.

```
var x = {
    ten: 10, 
    thirty: function(){var a = 10; a += 20; return a}(), 
    fifty: 25+25};
```

x is now an object which looks like:

```
ten: 10
thirty: 30
fifty: 50
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a function passing necessary arguments and use that for your `comments` property something like:

```
comments: (/* return value from your function */)
```